# spring @value use with properties file outside executable jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I want to configure and load the properties file so that it is not included in the jar.
How do I load a props file in the same location as a jar instead of a classpath?

The existing configuration is as follows.

xml setting
`<util:properties id="mainProps" location="classpath:config.properties" />`

java code
`@Value("#{mainProps['message.timeout']}")
 private Long timeout;`

Can I modify the spring util setting to preserve usage?
Or can it be used in other ways?

Comment: Read the file which parallel to jar (outside jar) using `FileInputStream` then `Properties` class having method `load()` which takes `File` object and returns `Properties` object.

Comment: or you can even use, `<util:properties id="mainProps" location="file:d:/config.properties"/>` considering you have `config.properties` on D:\ drive

Comment: @Amogh First of all, thank you for your feedback. If you use the second `file: d: /config.properties "`, can not you use a relative path without putting it in `d:`?  Like looking in the same path as jar

Comment: The what about first approach?

Comment: @Amogh The first approach has too many places to be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<util:properties id="mainProps" location="file:<full path to file>"/>` as mentioned by @Amogh.

If you do not want to use full path in your XML file or path can be different on different PCs you can create environmental variable (like `PATH_TO_CONFIG`) on PC which is pointing to that config file and use it

`@Value("#{environment.PATH_TO_CONFIG}")` or  `<util:properties id="mainProps" location="file#{environment['PATH_TO_CONFIG']}"/>`

Comment: Is it possible to use it as a relative path because it is also used in linux? Just as `./config.properties` is read as an absolute path in the same position

Comment: oh sorry.. `location="file:./config.properties"` is solved the problem.